# Motion blur in Flutter?

Tags: flutter, animation, flutter-layout, flutter-animation, motion-blur

I have been using Google Flutter for a recent project. And was wondering if we can apply motion blur in the widget animation. It just makes animations more realistic and soothing. I couldn't find any resources available regarding this.

Has anyone given it a try?

Comment: This is actually a very great question, since motion blur could make any animation smoother, and give it more 'ios look'. I'll follow your question.

Answer (score 1):

I just gave it a try myself. After finding nothing on the internet about this I came up with my own approach.

I have a spinning Image widget that has sharp edges and thus looks a bit ugly while rotating. I use a `RotationTransition` widget to animate its rotation.

```dart
RotationTransition(
      turns: Tween(begin: 1.0, end: 0.0).animate(
        CurvedAnimation(
          parent: animationController,
          curve: Curves.easeInOutQuad,
        ),
      ),
      child: ...,
),
```

As A child I put a Stack widget containing two `FadeTransition` widgets that each contain two Versions of the image. One is the default Image and one has the motion blur already applied to (in Photoshop).

```dart
Stack(
        children: [
          FadeTransition(
            opacity: Tween(begin: 1.0, end: 0.0).animate(
              CurvedAnimation(parent: animationController, curve: const FadeCurve(),
              ),
            ),
            child: Image.asset(
              "assets/images/image.png",
            ),
          ),
          FadeTransition(
            opacity: Tween(begin: 0.0, end: 1.0).animate(
              CurvedAnimation(parent: animationController, curve: const FadeCurve(),
              ),
            ),
            child: Image.asset(
              "assets/images/image_withMB.png",
            ),
          ),
        ],
      ),
```

Then I just created a custom `Curve` that changes the opacity in relation to the speed of the rotation.

```dart
class FadeCurve extends Curve {
  const FadeCurve();
  @override
  double transform(double t) {
    if (t <= 0.5) return pow(2 * t, 2).toDouble();
    return pow(2 - 2 * t, 2).toDouble();
  }
}
```

This of course only applies for images... and only static ones. But it might be exactly what you need.

Comment: Hi @MindStudio, I appreciate you giving it a try. From what I see this would not be the right approach to solve this problem. If you could put a `BackdropFilter` over the image/widget without using a pre-static blur image to replace it that should solve the problem. Tip: if you increase `BackdropFilter`'s sigma value of X more than Y or something similar, it would come way close to actual motion blur.